# Maximum in two columns dataframe python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have two columns in a dataframe, one of them are strings (country's) and the other are integers related to each country. How do I ask which country has the biggest value using python pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby('country').max()`

Comment: @anky_91 I'm sorry I didn't make this clear, but actually there are more columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Num=[*map(int, '352741845')], Country=[*'ABCDEFGHI']))

df

   Num Country
0    3       A
1    5       B
2    2       C
3    7       D
4    4       E
5    1       F
6    8       G
7    4       H
8    5       I
```

---

#### `idxmax`

```
df.loc[[df.Num.idxmax()]]

   Num Country
6    8       G
```

---

#### `nlargest`

```
df.nlargest(1, columns=['Num'])

   Num Country
6    8       G
```

---

#### `sort_values` and `tail`

```
df.sort_values('Num').tail(1)

   Num Country
6    8       G
```